# Is there a way to safely compile packages in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When writing PL/SQL packages I am a using Allround Automations PL/SQL Developer, not only, but also because of its handy feature of **[Safe Compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4GfC.png)**, which uses a temporary compilation object.
So it allows me to just compile my code and if I have any error in my syntax, nobody would be bothered.

Some colleagues are more comfortable working with Oracle SQL Developer (cur. 19.4.0), but it happens, that they invalidate a package and jobs or other overlying layers may get affected.

I was looking at the Preferences of Oracle SQL Developer, but did not found any useful settings, while searching for *comp*, *temp* or safe. May I overlooked something.

So my question is:
Is there a way to enable **Safe Compilation** of packages in Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: Restrict access for the developers to environments where invalid package cause no problem? Anyway one point can be usefull also in DEV environment, the *possibity to compile packages that are executed*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're working with an object in a database somewhere.

My best advice is create your own, local, private instance of Oracle to do your development work. Then when you're ready to share that code with your teammates, merge your changes to Git / Compile to the official Development instance.

VirtualBox, Docker, Oracle XE - there are many, easy ways to stand up a copy of Oracle on your machine for development purposes.

Other benefits include - you now get to be your own DBA/god. If you want to debug, step into an ASH report, there's no asking, you own the instance.

Comment: To be fair, I am not happy with your first sentence and must admit that I hoped for a positive answer. But I have to agree with the other parts of your answer, even if I think that's (at least for now/me) more an ideal setup, which has to be introduced.

But since we are talking about virtual/temporary environments, shouldn't it be possible to work with an temporary object. I have no idea how it works, but as I mentioned in the question it works with PL/SQL Developer. ;)

Comment: If it's doing what i think it's doing, you'd simply create your procedure as procedure_X, do the compile, if all is great, drop it, then compile it again against the original object

Comment: That's what I had guess, too, because the compilation time doubles.  
And after taking a look at your profile, may I ask you for a new feature. ;)

Comment: you could, but you're the first to ask for it @MartinBackasch